# Paypal API v2 request bearer token

Tags: paypal

The paypal order api allows to request information about an order:

```
curl -v -X GET https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/checkout/orders/orderID \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-H "Authorization: Bearer Access-Token"
```

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2/#orders_get

I hope haven't overseen something but I cannot find a documentation how to request the bearer for v2.

What I found is the explanations for v1:

```
curl -v https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token \
   -H "Accept: application/json" \
   -H "Accept-Language: en_US" \
   -u "client_id:secret" \
   -d "grant_type=client_credentials"
```

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/get-an-access-token-curl/

The combination works, but I would be happy if someone could correct me if I'm doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not doing anything wrong. No major revision of the oauth2 token authentication API has been released.